# How to tell while browsing the JDK source in github, which version of Java it is?

Tags: java, github

How to tell while browsing the JDK source in github, which version of Java it is?
For instance, I do not see anywhere it says which version this source of `Arrays` is:

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java

Comment: If you are talking about Java version itself the only way is to track down the commits/PRs for that code. It is a repo, there is not a division by version the last code there is the last version. You can however check the TAGs and see which files were added to it... But direct to a file not sure if it is possible

Comment: And if you are talking about the class/methods the `@since X` in the javadoc, for example (for Java 8) `@since 1.8` tells you when the method/class was added

Comment: GitHub lets you select a tag to browse. When you’re looking at the code on the master branch, it could include unreleased changes.